# what does this line mean

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i'm rather new to this but can anyone tell me what does this line mean?

```
predicted= linear.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression().fit()` expects an array of the `(# of rows, 1)` shape.

Demo:

```
In [52]: x_train= [5.5997066,4.759385,2.573958,5.586931,3.019574,4.296047,1.586953,0.5997066,3.683957]

In [53]: linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
<PYTHON_PATH>\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data
 is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshap
e(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1 9]
```

let's make it happy:

```
In [54]: x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(len(x_train), -1)

In [55]: x_train.shape
Out[55]: (9, 1)

In [56]: linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
Out[56]: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
```

**UPDATE:** the same also applies to `x_test` array:

```
In [60]: x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 1)

In [61]: x_test.shape
Out[61]: (5, 1)

In [62]: predicted= linear.predict(x_test)

In [63]: predicted
Out[63]: array([ 5.7559457,  5.7559457,  5.7559457,  5.7559457,  5.7559457])
```

Comment: hi , sorry but i got this error after changing it accordinly : "ValueError: shapes (1,5) and (1,1) not aligned: 5 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)"

Comment: @AwArAw, well, the same also applies to `x_test`

Comment: nice ! it doesn't have anymore errors , thanks a lot guys ! But one question , cause my purpose is to plot a linear graph out but it doesnt display any graph . Anything that i'm missing out here to plot out the graph based on these set of numbers?

Comment: will upvote once my reputation reached the eligible limit! thanks!

Comment: hi , sorry but i suddenly got this error "NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined" out of no where when i reopen the browser . Is it i have to define it somewhere?

Comment: @AwArAw, i guess you would need to give us more details... What does it have to do with a browser? Are you working in `Jupyter`? Did you define `x_train` in your current Python "session"? etc....